# In Wordpress how can I create a page which has 3 col-md-4 blocks in a container?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a normal wordpress page as part of a responsive bootstrap theme where I can explicitly assign html blocks specific CSS classes.

This will allow me to create a page where I have 3 equally sized blocks each with col-md-4 using bootstrap? Essentially in my wordpress page I want:

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">area 1</div>
<div class="col-md-4">area 2</div>
<div class="col-md-4">area 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I do not see how to do this when I am in the page editor, there is no place for html editting - please can somebody help me:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on the 'Text' tab on the top right of the editor to add HTML markup.

Comment: Had no idea it would be so simple!